# "would have had to pay" vs "have to pay"

Tags: present-perfect, conditional-constructions, present-tense

> If you are willing to start a business or move your existing business
>   to Russia, you may be able to obtain Russian citizenship within three
>   years by merely paying taxes you *would have had* to pay anyway.

Why the writer does not simply says "by merely paying taxes you *have to* pay anyway" ? why he uses present perfect here not just the simple present form?

Also, Why does he uses would ? Is it because he *imagines* if-situation here (paying taxes) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because he imagines if-situation here

That's right. By using the conditional with *would*, the writer is saying that even if you went with the first option, you would still have to pay the taxes. The implication is that this second option is better because you get its benefits (the citizenship within 3 years) since no matter which you choose you would still have to pay the taxes.

In explaining the *"taxes you would have had to pay anyway"* you could say *"taxes you would have had to pay anyway had you chosen not to move to Russia"*. It implies that in the current tense we're talking about the second option as if we've already chosen it, and then considering what would have happened if we chose the first option.

Comment: You mean the writer has in his mind the "if clause" (You would have had to pay, if you chose it ) right ? 

Very helpful , thank you.

Comment: It means you would have had to pay regardless of which you choice you made. Glad to help :)

Comment: 1)What about "**will** have had to" ? 2)BTW, I think since we cant say will/would have **must**, we need to use **have to** as matter of the fact that it has perfect or past form.